# Dart - Populate a Map programatically from an enum and a List

Tags: dart, enums

I want to populate a Map programatically but i don't know how to do that. Also i need that `tagname`to be constant.

I made manually this, but if you have a thousand of Tag values, you have to write a thousand of lines of code:

```
enum Tag { tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5 }

Map<Tag, String> tagname = {
  Tag.values[0]: 'Tag 1',
  Tag.values[1]: 'Tag 2',
  Tag.values[2]: 'Tag 3',
  Tag.values[3]: 'Tag 4',
  Tag.values[4]: 'Tag 5',
};
```

I want to populate `tagname` with:

```
const List<String> tagtitles = ['Tag 1', 'Tag 2', 'Tag 3', 'Tag 4'];
```

and if `tagtitles.lenght` < `Tag.values.lenght` then populate with 'empty' String.

Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you assume that the tagTitles and the Tag enum have the same order of items, you can do the following:

```
enum Tag { tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4 }

const List<String> tagTitles = ['Tag 1', 'Tag 2', 'Tag 3'];
Map<Tag, String> tagName = Map();
Tag.values.asMap().forEach((index, tag) =>
    tagName[tag] = index < tagTitles.length ? tagTitles[index] : 'empty');
```

The map will look something like this

```
{Tag.tag1: Tag 1, Tag.tag2: Tag 2, Tag.tag3: Tag 3, Tag.tag4: empty}
```

And you can use `tagName[Tag.tag1]` to access a item in the map.

Comment: So close, but i need that `tagName` to be constant, then, it must be assigned in the declaration.

Comment: You can create the map using ``final``. This allows the values inside the Map to be reassigned but the property itself no. If you need the Map to be ``const``, then you would have to set the values of the map in compile time, that said, you would need to have 1 thousand lines of code if you have 1 thousand items.

Comment: That's completely true. I was wanting to do something incoherent. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way would probably be:

```
var tagName = {for (var tag in Tag.values)
    tag: (tag.index < tagTitles.length ? tagTitles[tag.index] : "empty")};
```

It still cannot be constant.